# Parallel computing

Tags: python

I have a two dimensional table (Matrix)
I need to process each line in this matrix independently from the others.
The process of each line is time consuming.
I'd like to use parallel computing resources in our university (Canadian Grid something)

Can I have some advise on how to start ? I never used parallel computing before.

Thanks :)

Comment: perhaps talk to your lecturer/TA/professor....

Comment: For python you want to look at the `multiprocessing` library, or `threading` will suffice if all the heavy work is in C code.  Doubtful anyone here can help you to interface with the computing resources in your university, unless you by chance find someone else from your uni... !

Comment: FYI... clarification on Wim's note on threading: "...if all the heavy work is in C..." he (she?) said that because python's global interpreter lock does not allow multiple threads to run concurrently. They single step. You get around this by doing your work in C (the interpreter lock is released when the code transfers to C), or by using the multiprocessing module that he mentioned, because each thread then runs in a separate process. Both of these have heavy overhead, though, so if you really want performance, look at posix threads under C, or Java threads.

Answer (score 6):

Start here: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html

Be sure to read this: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#examples

This may be helpful: http://www.slideshare.net/pvergain/multiprocessing-with-python-presentation.

While excellent, it includes threads and multiprocessing, even though multiprocessing is often far, far superior to attempting multi-threading.

For Grid computing, multi-threading is largely useless.

Also, you probably also want to read up on [celery](http://celeryproject.org/).

Answer (score 5):

I am one of the developper of a new library called [scoop](https://code.google.com/p/scoop/).

It was built exactly for this purpose (grid or super-computing, scientific computing). I suggest you give it a try.

In your case, all you would have to do is a call like this:

```
futures.map(YourFunc, matrixLine)
```

It will then be distributed on your grid or whatever environment you choose.

Comment: I don't see anywhere to add feedback for Scoop on your webpage, so just a quick note here.  Scoop's installation process for Windows 7 could use some attention.  I was unable to get it to work.  Feel free to contact me for more details.

Comment: Feel free to report any issue on the [scoop mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scoop-users)  for a quicker answer. Please note that scoop is still in its beta stage but we welcome any feedback that will help getting it better. We will look into this issue shortly.

Comment: Wow, amazing to see the birth of SCOOP :p I love it!

Answer (score 0):

Like the commentators have said, find someone to talk to in your university.  The answer to your question will be specific to what software is installed on the grid.  If you have access to a grid, it's highly likely you also have access to a person whose job it is to answer your questions (and they will be pleased to help) - find this person!

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, I would say: first have a look at [`numpy`](https://numpy.org).
Numpy provides methods to compute the columns and rows in a vectorized manner with nearly `C` speed. Depending on your problem, this could be faster than parallel computation with pure `CPython`.

You can than use parallel computing with `numpy`-arrays to get a really big speed up.
Possible ways to do this is using `multiprocessing` or [Ipython](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/index.html) on a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you use C++/C for performing this computation. You can use the OpenMP API using the **#include<omp.h>** header. You can start your parallel region using the **#pragma amp parallel** directive. Since you are parallelising a for-loop for computing your matrix multiplication, you can use **#pragma omp parallel for { }** to start your for-loop inside the parallel region. OpenMP will automatically take care of the process synchronisation.

Check this out for a sample code: https://gist.github.com/metallurgix/0dfafc03215ce89fc595

Remember to use a big matrix to see actual improvements in speed. A smaller matrix will perform poorly in fact due to increased task overhead created due to forking and joining the multiple threads.

You can also check out MPI if you want to parallelise your code using multiple processors instead of multiple threads.